# Exception logging in Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

Why concept of exception logging ([`IExceptionLogger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.exceptionhandling.iexceptionlogger(v=vs.118).aspx)) ever exists if there is [`IExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.iexceptionfilter(v=vs.118).aspx) interface in the framework?

Comment: we typically use the exception filters to catch exceptions

Comment: did you take a look at http://www.strathweb.com/2014/03/asp-net-web-api-exception-logging-raygun-io/

Comment: Yes, that's why corresponding concrete classes exist. But why do we have  a special interface for error logging?

Comment: I never got an answer to basically the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476475/does-iexceptionlogger-deprecate-the-need-for-exceptionfilterattribute-in-web-api) but I came to the conclusion that the `IExceptionLogger` is superior.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidPeden! My personal feeling is that Web API is kind of experimental  fork (especially after the news when they're gonna merge it to MVC 6) but I'd like to have more valid opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Today there’s no easy way in Web API to log or handle errors globally. Some unhandled exceptions can be processed via exception filters, but there are a number of cases that exception filters can’t handle. For example:

```
Exceptions thrown from controller constructors
Exceptions thrown from message handlers
Exceptions thrown during routing
Exceptions thrown during response content serialization
```

More [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling)

Comment: These are valid points. But as far as I know WebAPI is based on top of standard ASP.NET modules architecture, isn't it? Which already has a mechanism for processing of unhandled errors? Nevertheless, if we have `IExceptionFilter` extension point why do we need a separate one for logging?

Comment: IMHO, we can take Web API to be a standalone and not based on the ASP.Net modules as it can be self hosted and can have no dependency on system.web as such. Only MVC is still tied to the ASP.Net architecture. You have to view Web API as one that can be hosted without IIS in which case we cannot leverage ASP.Net modules, hence it is always a right practice to have used the corresponding featuers

Comment: In case, at later point of time, you have to move web api to run on a apache / ngix server without asp.net, this is where you will be benefiting of the new interfaces, they are dependency injectable as compared to the traiditional ASP.Net modules

Comment: You can view of this feature as a SoC pattern. Please share your thoughts